# boxes appear on computer start up

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have 3 questions that appear as boxes on screen when my computer starts. Some of my computer keys are around the wrong way so / is reversed so should be thither way round in this example.
A box appears when the computer is turned on that reads

Windows cannot find 'C/program files(x86)/search extensions/clinet.exe. make sure you typed the name correctly and start again.

Most of the time I've overcome this by simply clicking ok and the box disappears. AVG anti virus free won't remove it. It is there everytime the computer is starts.
Can you help with just this one of the problems ?

Comment: welcome to superuser, sorry about not figuring out this word."? thither ?" Also you could add the other problems as an over all example

Answer (score 0):

You can open `Startup` tab in `Task Manager` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and disable the startup application (if it's there).

Answer (score 0):

Could be Rocket Tab adware. If the steps at 
https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-search-extensions-client-exe-popup/ sound too intimidating, ask someone more versed for help.